# Android MVP, how to coordinate multiple views?

Tags: android, mvp

I have a presenter `P`. It is meant to control everything for some type of view `V`. I have multiple views like this: `V1`, `V2`, ... `Vn`. Interacting with one view `Vx`, can have effects on other another views `Vy`.

What is the best way to coordinate this? Should the presenters talk to each other? Should the presenter have references to all views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One View should know nothing about other ones. The View should communicate with its Presenter only. One Presenter also shouldn't know about other Presenters. To avoid presenters cohesion use events (EventBus, Otto, RxJava Subjects...).

Comment: Could the main view talk to main presenter, which talks to main view and sub/nested views. And sub/nested views talk to their own presenters?

Comment: HI Deal,  What do you mean by the nested view? Hierarchically in XML? Logically? Give an example. If you have several views on the screen and some view are logically nested, it's better to use flat view-presenter structure without any nesting. Let's look at Gmail App screen example  in [this  article](http://hannesdorfmann.com/mosby/mvp/). Could you point to the nested view in this example?

Comment: In addition: Specific View should interact with its Presenter only. And it's better if specific Presenter doesn't interact with any View except for its own. If Presenter like to change smth in another view, it should poke the Presenter of this View (for example, using event bus) or influence to another view through the Model.

Comment: The Inbox view in this example has a list of items. That's kind of what I'm referring to as nested views. Should each of those have a presenter?

Comment: I suppose you mean that's the logical hierarchy, so your recommendation is to use a single presenter here. I guess I'm just a bit conflicted... If we have to implement the functionality to 'highlight on long tap', it feels like this logic should live in the presenter for every single item, and somehow communicate (maybe listener) back to the full view to keep a total count. But at the same time, it feels awkward to communicate from main presenter to item presenter through an event bus here.

Comment: In case of emails list I'd implement whole list as a single View with the single Presenter. When the user does long tap View call Presenter.itemLongTap. The Presenter marks the item as highlighted in in its internal list (or ViewModel) and call View.highlightItem().

Answer (score 1):

One approach is presenter `P` holding view `V` and view `V` inherit `V1`, `V2`,...`Vn`. Methods will be accessible for `V` across all View containers (Fragments and Activities).

```
public interface MainView extends BaseView, ErrorView{ //V
  void showProducts(@Nullable List<Product> products);
} 


public interface BaseView{ //V1 
   void setLoading(boolean loading);
   void showConfirmationDialog(@StringRes int title, @StringRes int message);
}

public interface ErrorView{ //V2
  void showErrorSnackBar(@StringRes int message);
}


public class ProductListFragment extends ... implements MainView{


}
```

In my experience, this works fine, beside the clutter and empty methods, which is not good in terms of readability.

Holding references of other Presenters inside your main presenter is fine as long as you ensure they are alive. This could lead to anti-pattern.

Another approach is holding each presenter separately and each of them consume the events standalone:

```
@Override
public void showProducts(List<Product> products){
   // do something with products that Presenter1 has dispatched for presenting
   presenter2.doSomethingOnProducts();
}
```

This is seamless communication between the interested parties in the result.

Mixing `Observer` pattern with MVP is fine too.

Comment: Can you clarify
"view `V` inherit `V1`, `V2`,...`Vn`. Methods will be accessible for V across all View containers."
I'm not sure I follow what 'inherit' means here. The V views are all the same time, it's just that there a lot of them contained in a larger view (picture list view)

Comment: @Deal See my edit with minimalistic example snippet.